# Eclipse PDE: how to get the display value of IMarker type

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

This looks like a simple problem but I didn't get any idea from google. In Eclipse IDE, when I worked with java projects, the "Problems" view will show the errors and warnings dynamically. I am trying to include a similar feature in my PDE project. I got the IMarker objects

```
IMarker[] markers = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findMarkers(IMarker.PROBLEM, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
```

Each object has the type "org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem". This is the constant value of JAVA_MODEL_PROBLEM_MARKER defined in IJavaModelMarker. On the IDE's "Markers" view, it will display as "Java Problems". I am not sure how to get the mapping between "org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem" and "Java Problems"? Any information is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is declared using the 'name' attribute of the extension point defining the marker in the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` plugin:

```xml
<extension id="problem" point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers"
           name="Java Problems">
    <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker"/>
    <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"/>
    <persistent value="true"/>
    <attribute name="id"/>
    <attribute name="flags"/>
    <attribute name="arguments"/>
    <attribute name="categoryId"/>
</extension>
```

So to get this value you need to read all the marker extension points and find the one you want:

```
IExtensionPoint point = Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getExtensionPoint(ResourcesPlugin.PI_RESOURCES,
            ResourcesPlugin.PT_MARKERS);

IExtension [] extensions = point.getExtensions();

for (IExtension extension : extensions) {
    String id = ext.getUniqueIdentifier();

    if ("org.eclipse.jdt.core.problem".equals(id)) {
       String label = ext.getLabel();

       // TODO save the label
    }
}
```

Details taken from `org.eclipse.ui.views.markers.internal.MarkerTypesModel`